# Check instance with java.lang.reflect.Type

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I'm looking for a way to find out if an object `x` is an instance
of a generic type. For example `List<String>`.

Inspired by the Super-Type-Token idiom I can retrieve the `java.lang.reflect.Type` at runtime with follwing code

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TypeReference<List<String>> ref = new TypeReference<List<String>>() {};
        System.out.println(ref.getType());
        System.out.println(ref.getType().getClass());
    }

    abstract static class TypeReference<T> {
        private final Type type;

        protected TypeReference() {
            ParameterizedType superclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
            type = superclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        }

        public Type getType() {
            return type;
        }
    }
}
```

The output is

```
java.util.List<java.lang.String>
class sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl
```

How can I use this information for dynamic casting or type checking?

<sup>Background is I'm currently writing a heterogeneous type-safe container lib and want to add support for generic types https://bitbucket.org/mbeyene/jam</sup>

Comment: The short answer is that you can't.  You've constructed an object representing the generic type, sure, but you can't actually use it to determine the generic type of another object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must notice that you're using a parameterized type as type argument for `TypeReference<T>` instance. So you would need to cast it to `ParameterizedType` at the caller end, and get the raw type from that.

Then you can cast that rawtype to `Class<?>` type, and use `Class#isInstance()` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TypeReference<List<String>> ref = new TypeReference<List<String>>() {};

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    Type rawType = ((ParameterizedType)ref.getType()).getRawType();
    boolean listIsInstanceOfRawType = ((Class<?>)(rawType)).isInstance(list));

    System.out.println(listIsInstanceOfRawType); // true
}
```

Note that, you can't check instanceof against a parameterized type - `List<String>` or `List<Integer>`, as that doesn't make sense. Both of them are nothing but `List` at runtime. What I mean is:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

System.out.println(list instanceof List<String>);  // Won't compile
System.out.println(list instanceof List);          // You've to do this.

// The reason is, this is true
System.out.println(new ArrayList<String>().getClass() == new ArrayList<Integer>().getClass());   // true
```

Comment: This misleads the OP into thinking that this will actually check the generics part.  It won't.

Comment: @mike Well, this is the best you can get.

Comment: What a pity. I'm writing a heterogeneous type-safe container and want to add support for generics.